# Matrix multiplication function?

Tags: assemblyscript

How do you write a matrix multiplication function? Takes two matrices outputs one.
The documentation on [assemblyscript.org](https://www.assemblyscript.org/) is pretty short, Float64Array though is a valid type among [these](https://www.assemblyscript.org/stdlib/typedarray.html#variants) but that's 1D so...

Comment: The documentation seems decent to me, but the UI design makes it a bit hard to navigate, IMO. You probably want Arrays which are part of the standard library. https://www.assemblyscript.org/stdlib/array.html

Answer (score 0):

AssemblyScript's stdlib is modeled after JavaScript's stdlib, so there are no matrix operations.  However, here is a library that might work for you: https://github.com/JustinParratt/big-mult